# How do I do select into from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, sql-insert

Basically I want to run a SQL statement like this, but I can't due to errors.
Not sure why?

```
INSERT INTO allevent (eventname) 
VALUES (select username from registered)
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need of parentheses around the `SELECT` statement in your query.

```
 INSERT INTO allevent (eventname) 
 SELECT username FROM registered
```

Parentheses with `VALUES` required, where some places like below:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (fieldname) 
VALUES ('field 01'), ('field 02');
```

Please find the syntax for the [`INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement.

Comment: I also want to answer this kind simple question (dog face emoji)